# How do we know whether we use WSS only or MOSS?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I have installed WSS 3.0 sp1 in windows server 2003 and it runs successfully now. My problem is does this version of WSS, includes the MOSS 2007 or is it just the WSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not include MOSS 2007. They are two different products. MOSS is a superset of WSS in that it is built upon WSS, and contains additional features. See the article [Windows SharePoint Services v3.0 vs Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/moss_vs_wss.htm).

BTW: In case you weren't aware, [WSS 3.0 SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=79bada82-c13f-44c1-bdc1-d0447337051b&displaylang=en) is the latest service pack.